# How to display the path without alias?

Tags: 8, forms, commerce, uri, path-aliases

With Drupal 8 and Commerce 2.10

I created a php code to display the link of my store.

When I go to the link, it displays:

```
https://www.domaine.com/shop/name
```

I want to display without alias:

```
https://www.domaine.com/store/id
```

How to do ?

```
$link = Link::createFromRoute($this->t('my business'), 'entity.commerce_store.canonical', ['commerce_store' => $store_id], ['attributes' => ['target' => '_blank']])->toString();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set the option `alias`:

```
$link = Link::createFromRoute(
  $this->t('my business'),
  'entity.commerce_store.canonical',
  ['commerce_store' => $store_id],
  ['alias' => TRUE, 'attributes' => ['target' => '_blank']]
)->toString();
```

Comment: Thank you, how to add at the end of my link `/cgv` ?

Comment: How is this connected to the question, aliased or not aliased?

Comment: I am with Drupal 8 and there is still the alias. I think adding an element at the end of the url will no longer use the alias.

Comment: I just realized that the problem was related to Drupal and the module`https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto`. So the only way to get the url `/store/3` is to add an item to the end `/store/3/cgv` this way the url will not be rewritten by Drupal. How to add an item at the end ?

Comment: Yes, you could create a second route with the pattern `/store/3/cgv` and specifiy this route in the link. But I don't think you need to do this. The option added to the link will disable aliasing for the original route and you'll get  `store/3`. Or configure Pathauto to not create an alias for the original route in the first place.

Comment: I tested the answer but it does not work because pathauto redirects the url. I do not want to delete the redirrection for my store. I prefer to add `/cgv` at the end of the url. How to add this in my code ?

Comment: Redirecting is a different issue, this doesn't happen when you build the link, but when you visit the unaliased path. Probably you have installed the Redirect module.